# How do i put an X on the right side of a <a> block?

Tags: html, css

if i remove a.three display block this shows up fine. However what i want is the X to be at the right side. I tried float: right but it puts the x on the next line. How do i get the X on the same line? Here is [some code](http://jsfiddle.net/NavCR/5/).

html

```
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><nobr>
            <a href="/a" class="one">a</a>
            <a href="/b" class="two">b</a>
            <a href="/c" class="three">c</a>
            </nobr></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Css

```
li a
{
    display: inline;
    background:red;
}
li a.two
{
    background:teal;
}

li a.three
{
    display: block;
    background:green;
}
```

-edit- I forgot to mention. All of the green must be clickable as the original and which is why i have the 3rd link as a block. All current solution does not have the green clickable. NOTE: I think i can change the javascript code to fix this BUT i dont know if css or js is the better solution. The code is inside a demo i modified from SoundManager which tweaks elements inside of the li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add `float` to an element is forces `display: block;`. Since your `a.three` is also `display:block` it forces the second div down a line.

I'm not 100% convinced I like this solution, but... `Add position: relative;` to the parent `li` making it a positioning container, and then use absolute positioning on `.div2`

[Updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/NavCR/13/)

```
li 
{
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}
li a.one
{
    float:left;
    background:red;
}
li a.two
{
    float:left;
    background:pink;
}

li a.three
{
    display:block;
    background:green;
}
.div2
{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You force a width of 100% on the LI block and than expect the X to be positioned to the right of it ?
Try a `<div>` around all lines `100%`.
Than the `<li>` with a fixed width or 90% or so, float left, and the X float right with a width of 8% of a fixed number.

Answer (score 0):

You're not very clear on what you want.
Would this http://jsfiddle.net/bmpuj/ be a solution?

```
li 
{
    width:100%;
}
li a.one
{
    float:left;
    background:red;
}
li a.two
{
    float:left;
    background:pink;
}

li a.three
{
    float: left;
    background:green;
}
.container
{
    background: green;
    width: 100%;
}
.div2
{
    float: right;

}
```